# javascript, 2 different function on a unique button, with 2 events

Tags: javascript, html, function, events, button

I want to build a JS script, to add 2 onClick events in 1 single button. This 2 events must works separately:
ex.
first click on button: event A

second click on the same button: event B

that's my code:

html button: press it once to how a div, press it again to show another div

```
<button id="add-form" class="add"><a class="btn" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x"></i></a></button>-->

...
...

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
```

the 2 div are hidden at start

```
  $("#div2").hide();
  $("#div3").hide()
```

that's the function to(try) show the 2 divs, once at time

```
    $("#add-form").click(function(){
      $("#viaggio2").fadeIn();
    }$("#add-form").click(function(){
      ("#viaggio3").fadeIn();
    });

  });
  </script>
```

PS. Sorry for my bad english, and ty everyone who try to help me! :)

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: What did you try? can you show your code.

Answer (score 3):

you can do this simply in [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/)

```
$( "#target" ).toggle(function() {
  alert( "calling function 1" );
}, function() {
  alert( "calling function 2" );
});
```

**Docs**

If more than two handlers are provided, .toggle() will cycle among all of them. For example, if there are three handlers, then the first handler will be called on the first click, the fourth click, the seventh click, and so on.

**Note**

> This method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in
>   jQuery 1.9. jQuery also provides an animation method named .toggle()
>   that toggles the visibility of elements. Whether the animation or the
>   event method is fired depends on the set of arguments passed.

But to your requirement it can be done easily with `toggleClass`

```
$("#add-form").click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("add-form add-form2")
      $("#viaggio2").fadeIn();})
$("#add-form2").click(function(){
$(this).toggleClass("add-form add-form2")
      $("#viaggio3").fadeIn();})
```

Comment: hmm i've tried it with my code, but it doesn't work.. my button's id is "#A" and the 2 divs which I've to show on 2 separate clicks are  id "#divA" and "#divB". So the code to show one at time is: `$("#A").toggle(function(){ $("#divA").show();], function(){ $("#divB").show();});` right?

Comment: @LucaZambon if you are using jQuery `>1.9` it won't work so i edited the answer check it once

Comment: thank you dude for the reply, but it still not working.. With this method, it still showing me all the 2 events in the same click.

Comment: @LucaZambon make sure you have the class name  if possible invite to chat

Comment: @LucaZambon i have miss spelled your ids `viaggio2` now i have corrected hope this works

Answer (score 1):

You can attach one event but with counter for ex:

```
 var condition = 0;

 document.querySelector('.my-button').addEventListener('click', function() {

  if(condition === 0) { /* logic 1 */
  else if (condition === 1) { /* logic 2 */}

  condition++;
 });
```

Comment: i assume he doesn't want to 'toggle' - but yes, it toggling, the he'll have to reset the counter.

Comment: He said only: one -> A, second -> B, he didn't say third -> A

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery `.toggle()` method has some elegance to it, but it does come with some extra functionality you may not be expecting. Be sure to read the documentation before implementing.

A more vanilla approach would be something like this:

```
// keep track of button clicks
var buttonClickCount = 0;

document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function(){

  // increment the button click count
  ++buttonClickCount;

  // on the first click, eventA
  if(buttonClickCount===1){
    eventA();
  }

  // on the second click, eventB
  if(buttonClickCount===2){
    eventB();
  }
});

function eventA(){
  console.log('Event A');
}

function eventB(){
  console.log('Event B');
}
```